# Is damage over time affected by crits?

Tags: diablo-iii

From the [1.0.3 patch notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6457499/):

> Damage Over Time (DoT) skills will now properly benefit from items with the +Critical Chance affix

So, hypothetically, if I'm using a demon hunter with 2.5 attacks per second, and I use impale with 2 seconds of bleeding, then do I get 5 chances to crit from one impale?

Comment: Note that they have always been able to crit, they just weren't getting the correct bonus to crit previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you wanted to take your auto-attacks into account. No if you are ONLY taking the Impale ability into account.

**If you're considering auto-attacks and impale critting in the same second:**

- 2 chances to crit from auto-attack
- 1 chance from the impale ability itself
- 2 over 2 seconds from the impale ability's rune.

**If you're considering ONLY impale and the rune's total effect:**

- 1 chance from the impale ability itself
- 2 over 2 seconds from the impale ability's runed DoT effect.

What the Damage Over Time now affecting crits means is that now DoT abilities themselves benefit from crit on each tick of the DoT's damage. For example, impale's runed bleed does 125% weapon damage over 2 seconds, which means it deals 62.5% weapon damage every second. The individual DoT ticks that do 62.5% weapon damage and happen once a second are what now benefit from crit.

Comment: Why are you counting two auto-attacks when the question discusses a single Impale? Am I missing something?

Comment: Since the asker mentioned his auto-attack speed I figured he wanted that factor counted in for a total in seconds. I'll add some details to my answer as my assumption may have been wrong.